# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to JFactory::getSession() Joomla 3

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0, virtuemart

Hello i have Joomla 3 and virtue-mart 3 i have installed a module called ajax cart module for showing products in cart but when i published and provide position to this module i have faced some critical error from Joomla libraries and virtue-mart cart file and error like this.

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to JFactory::getSession() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /data/home/krcisinl/public_html/isurplus/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/cart.php on line 112 and defined in /data/home/krcisinl/public_html/isurplus/libraries/joomla/factory.php on line 171
```

i do not why this error occurs and how to solve this. 
and here my cart page code where i get error.

```
public static function getCart($forceNew=false, $options = array(), $cartData=NULL) {

    //What does this here? for json stuff?
    if (!class_exists('JTable')) require(VMPATH_LIBS . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'database' . DS . 'table.php');

    if(empty(self::$_cart) or $forceNew){

        self::$_cart = new VirtueMartCart;

        if (empty($cartData)) {
            **$session = JFactory::getSession($options);**
            $cartSession = $session->get('vmcart', 0, 'vm');
            if (!empty($cartSession)) {
                $sessionCart = (object)json_decode( $cartSession ,true);

                if(empty($sessionCart->cartProductsData) or ($sessionCart->_guest and $sessionCart->_guest!=JFactory::getUser()->guest)){
                    self::$_cart->loadCart($sessionCart);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $cartSession=$sessionCart=$cartData;
        }
```

I have faced error on this line

```
**$session = JFactory::getSession($options);**
```

this is my cart page code

Comment: Did you write the code in the files?

Comment: here is link where my site live http://isurplus.kr.cisinlive.com/

Comment: What does `$options` contain? The error clearly tells you that it is not an array, which is what it should be.